# Why does "DB2 Recovery Expert" web console doesn't enable the Run and Next button?

Tags: db2, tools, db2-luw

Sometimes, when performing the Log Analysis and Recovery options in the Recovery Expert web console, the buttons "Next" and/or "Run" aren't enabled. 
This is strange because we do provide all the optins requested to proceed with the operation. I am using DB2 R.E. 5.1, so I'm not sure about other versions have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that the tool identified that there's some information missing. Still in my case everything was there. So, I've found that the solution for my issue was just because, even if you don't have an alternative path for logs or backups, you still have to specify them when running these operations.

Sometimes even doing so they might not enable instantly. You must go "Previous" and then "Next" to make the web console notice the changes.